# Convert ArcGIS network dataset 10.1 to 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, network-analyst

I am using ArcMap 10 and have a network dataset made ​​with ArcGIS 10.1.

I can not open the network dataset for the version of my Arcmap.

Is there a tool or way to convert the network dataset from 10.1 to 10 without having to redo the network dataset?

Comment: Do you have any service packs on the 10.0 install? The What's New at 10.1 doc says that arcgis should be at 10.0 sp 2 to be compatible with 10.1 gdb. I don't know if this includes network datasets. They can't be using any new-at-10.1 capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to downgrade the network dataset.
The reason for that is that in Ver. 10.1  Esri changed the format of the Feature Dateset. Any try to export the ver. 10.1 Network dataset will automatically upgrade the target GDB to the current version. There is no way to do it in ver. 10.0 as well, since it will not recognize the network at all..

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you have not updated to 10.2.1?  This would solve your compatibility issue.  ArcGIS 10 is not a very stable release.

Comment: I do not understand your point, can you explain me

Comment: I need to make a network dataset for use in arcgis 10 the fastest way

Comment: @user22547 My point was asking why you are using ArcGIS 10 and not 10.2.1.

Comment: I do have access arcgis 10.1 and 10.2, but my client, my client only has version arcgis 10

Comment: As you already know, locators built in ArcGIS 10 are not compatible with ArcGIS 10.1</a> nor have I found a tool which can do this.  Your best bet is to upgrade your client to a modern version of ArcGIS or run ArcGIS 10 on a machine/virtual machine to develop for them. http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00250000001w000000